# Putting column values from text file into a list in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, duplicates, text-files

I have a text file like this:

```
a    w
b    x
c,d  y
e,f  z
```

And I want to get the values of the first column into a list without duplicates. For now I get the values from the first column, which I am doing like this:

```
f=open("file.txt","r")
lines=f.readlines()
firstCol=[]
for x in lines:
    firstCol.append(x.split('   ')[0])
f.close()
```

In the next step I want to separate the values by a comma delimiter the same way I did before, but then I get an output like this:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

How can I convert this into a one dimensional thing to be able to remove duplicates afterwards? 
I am a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it immediately after the first split and must use extend instead of append.

```
f=open("file.txt","r")
lines=f.readlines()
firstCol=[]
for x in lines:
    firstCol.extend(x.split(' ')[0].split(','))
f.close()

print(firstCol)
```

Result

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Or if you want to keep the firstCol

```
f=open("file.txt","r")
lines=f.readlines()
firstCol=[]
for x in lines:
    firstCol.append(x.split(' ')[0])
f.close()

one_dimension = []
for col in firstCol:
    one_dimension.extend(col.split(','))

print(firstCol)
print(one_dimension)
```

Result

```
['a', 'b', 'c,d', 'e,f']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `itertools.chain` to flatten your list of lists and then you can use the built-in class `set` to remove the duplicates :

```
from itertools import chain

l = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
set(chain.from_iterable(l))
# {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```

---

to flatten your list you can also use a list comprehension:

```
my_l = [e for i in l for e in i]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

same with 2 simple `for` loops:

```
my_l = []

for i in l:
    for e in i:
        my_l.append(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possible solution 1

If your are fine with your code, you can keep like that and remove duplicates from a list of lists executing the following:

```py
import itertools

firstCol.sort()
firstCol = list(x for x,_ in itertools.groupby(firstCol))
```

## Possible solution 2

If you want to convert the list of lists into one list of items:

```py
firstCol = [x for y in firstCol for x in y]
```

If you want to also remove duplicates:

```py
firstCol = list(set([x for y in firstCol for x in y]))
```